# create canvas/board in android app

Tags: android

I want to create `canvas/board` in my android application. I want to add following functionality in `canvas/board`.

- Add Multiple Pictures through camera (Rotate pictures, reduce picture sizes)
- Add Text
- Add Shapes (Circle, Rectangular etc)
- Redo/Undo

Which control is used for creating such a canvas. Please guide me for developing such a canvas in android.

Following is the `canvas/board` example image - [link](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B5sKydOckuY2akxkaUtOdTFQTjA&usp=sharing)

Comment: Have you tried on Google? If you didn't see this http://www.techiecommunity.net/Android/Android-Canvas-Draw-Example,http://danielnadeau.blogspot.in/2012/01/android-canvas-beginners-tutorial.html,https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/707993-how-to-draw-2d-object-in-android-with-a-canvas

Answer (score 0):

I have worked on similar kind of thing and have a working demo. 
You can find it on [Android Canvas Painting Demo](http://trivedihardik.wordpress.com/2013/01/24/android-canvas-painting-demo/)

I hope it will help you.